# exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, database, innodb

When I try to grab some values from database, I end up getting an error. Here's my code:

```
function pokaz_tabela_plany($klasa, $dzien) {

    global $conn;
    $q = $conn->prepare('select * from `plany` where `id_klasy`='.$klasa.' and `id_dnia`='.$dzien.' order by `id_lekcji` asc;');
    $q->execute();

    foreach($q as $row) {

        $sql1 = 'select `godz_poczatek` from `lekcje` where `id`='.$row['id_lekcji'].';';
        $x = $conn->prepare($sql1);
        $x->execute();
        $godzina = $x->fetchColumn(); // works great

        $sql2 = 'select `nazwa_przedmiotu` from `przedmioty` where `id`='.$row['id_przedmiotu'].';';
        $w = $conn->prepare($sql2);
        $w->execute();
        $przedmiot = $w->fetchColumn(); // error

        $sql3 = 'select `symbol` from `nauczyciele` where `id`='.$row['id_nauczyciela'].';';
        $r = $conn->prepare($sql3);
        $r->execute();
        $nauczyciel = $r->fetchColumn(); // error

        $sql4 = 'select `symbol` from `sale` where `id`='.$row['id_sali'].';';
        $s = $conn->prepare($sql4);
        $s->execute();
        $sala = $s->fetchColumn(); // error

        $tabela .= '<tr><td>'.$godzina.'</td><td>'.$przedmiot.'</td><td>'.$nauczyciel.'</td><td>'.$sala.'</td></tr>';

    }
    echo $tabela;
}
```

And execution of that function:

```
<?php pokaz_tabela_plany($_POST['wybierz_klase'],$_POST['wybierz_dzien']); ?>
```

I tried the same query with PHPMyAdmin's SQL input and it gives me proper values.

Comment: Excuse me sir, what language is that? maybe the proper Encoding should be given to the PDO Constructor.

Comment: This is Polish. I double checked encoding in the PDO constructor, the database, PHP file and even header.

Comment: When you get successfull results and you show them in the HTML, characters like this appear? "ą", "ć", "ł"?

Comment: Show your db structure

Comment: Yes, these characters appear properly. The main table's structure: http://nosiu.ml/screen.jpg

Comment: Yeah, NULL values generated errors. I added PDO::NULL_TO_STRING in my PDO constructor and now it works. Thread closed. Anyway, thanks for your help.